# Intellij Idea plugin repositories are not accessible

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, repository

Try to install a plugin. Idea could not connect to the repo. I looked through other questions like this, tried to turn off an antivirus software and a firewall, checked IPv4 option in the vm config (it's set to true). Any other ideas, please?

Idea is installed on a Win 10, through a ToolBox.
[image]

Comment: What error is logged into [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)? Do you have proxy in network? If you have it - configure it in IDE HTTP Proxy settings.

Comment: Don't have proxy, but set proxy in auto mode as it was recommended somewhere.

Comment: It's not possible to add log here because it's too long. There was a error at 14-Jan and related to an old project, not to current one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the path - installation root of Intellij contained Russian (non-ASCII) characters. I moved all the JetBrains tools to `c:/` and this solved the issue. This can be done via the ToolBox functionality.